# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working on new server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I deployed on a Apache server using Debian, a PHP software that uses mod_rewrite.

It's the basic `http://domain/path/var1/var2/` being redirected to `http://domain/path/index.php?par1=var1&par2=var2`

In my dev environment it works fine, but on this server it's not working. If I browse `http://domain/path/home/`, apache returns 404 for home folder. If I create a home folder it returns 403, and if I put a index.html inside it this file is served to browser.

phpinfo() reports mod_rewrite is enabled. I always imagined that it was just a matter of uncommenting its LoadModule for .htaccess starts working.

Is there anything else I could check to make it work?

Update: this is the folder's config, could this be blocking htaccess from working?

```
 <Directory /var/www>

            Options None
            AllowOverride None

            AuthType NTLM
            AuthName "Please provide Domain\login"
            require valid-user

            PythonAuthenHandler pyntlm
            PythonOption domain Domain
            PythonOption PDC ADhost
    </Directory>
```

I'll change it tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: Paste the content of your .htaccess file, will help to debug

Comment: I didn't post it because, since it's working on dev environment, it should work on this new server too. I'll post it tomorrow when I have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure your vhost to allow Override FileInfo somehow like that:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

Additionally: Did you restart your server after activating the module?

Comment: I restarted it, but I forgot to see its configuration. Is it in httpd.conf?

Comment: It didn't work. If I use `AllowOverride FileInfo` I start receiving Internal Server Error. If I use `AllowOverride All` it keeps returning 404.